# How to find out the content of a XML file using Unix Sed/Awk?

Tags: sed, awk, xml

I have a XML file(MyXML.xml) like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns3:GetAllInfoFromRest xmlns:ns2="http://com.lanuk.cfe/b2_7/service/objects" xmlns:ns3="http://com.lanuk.cfe/b2_7/service/operations">
            1111,GH43567,Hamburger,GET,278598655,\n000001,                    ,Kunal,Bhyuo,Ramond,856 K. 98 Rd,                                        ,                                        ,Tripura,AGT,INDIA,856987,                    ,S,S,S,8956,\666666
        </ns3:GetAllInfoFromRest>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Now i need to strip out the SOAP content and all the tag attributes from this xml and get only the string response `1111,GH43567,Hamburger,GET,278598655,\n000001,                    ,Kunal,Bhyuo,Ramond,856 K. 98 Rd,                                        ,                                        ,Tripura,AGT,INDIA,856987,                    ,S,S,S,8956,\666666`.

How can i do it with `awk` or  `sed` ?

I tried it in this  way :

```
$ xgawk -lxml 'XMLATTR["xmlns:ns3"]=="http://com.lanuk.cfe/b2_7/service/operations"{print $2}' MyXML.xml
```

But obviously I am making some mistake  due to which it is not working. 
Can some one suggest any other way around this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed/awk` are really about *regular expressions*.
check [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/135078) why parsing HTML/XML with regular expressions is a *bad* idea.

for XML you really need to build a DOM of the document and then find your information. there are cmdline tools like [xmlstar](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/) that allow you to get information out of XML-documents.

**but do not try using sed/awk to parse XML**

PS: of course, you might be able to create a simple regular expression that can extract the information needed on the files you happen to encounter in real life.
e.g. the following will print the 5th line of the document, which (in your example) holds the relevant information.

```
# stupid and naive approach:
sed '5!d' MyXML.xml
```

but this makes an assumption about the layout of the file, which has *nothing* to do with XML. it might work for a very specific generator of the given file, but is not guaranteed to work with any XML-file following the same *structure* (and structured data is what XML is all about)

Comment: There are also XML parsers in most scripting languages - Perl, Python, Ruby...

Comment: @TheDarkKnight - Though this answers your question, it's really not a good idea to be parsing structured data such as JSON or XML using sed and awk. Use a real parser specifically suited to the data!

Comment: @slm: Can you explain like what you mean by real parser?

Comment: @TheDarkKnight - sure. A tool such as http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/. Also in Perl there are modules for parsing JSON or XML which give you methods for querying/manipulating the XML/JSON.

Comment: @slm my answer is all about using tools like `xmlstar` (2nd paragraph) rather than trying to parse XML using sed&awk (first paragraph). i tried to make clear that my trivial sed-script does *not* parse XML at all

Comment: @umläute - my comments were just to DarkNight, I know you said that but I was reiterating it. We've seen this question come up enough that if others come across it I wanted it to be REALLY obvious not to use sed/awk for this kind of work.

Comment: @slm right you are; i have added some more emphasis in the answer on this topic